# Highcharts: Can I display only part of a series?

Tags: highcharts

I have a query regarding display of stock data in highstock.
Firstly:
I want to hide price of last 10 months from a total data of 60 months. I want the months to be displayed (i.e. x-axis should have all 60 months), but want the data to be displayed only for first 50 months.
Secondly:
If an event is triggered (say click) I want these last 10 prices also to be displayed (in additional to the original 50).

Is there a logic/pre-processing in Highcharts/Highstock that can make my implementation efficient such that I do not have to break up my JSON data files?

Answer (score 0):

So you can set serie with 50 points and after click event action, call http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint() function (in iteraction) which adds new points missing values.

Comment: The reason this approach wont solve my issue is because I want to show the complete xAxis right from the start i.e. I do not want the range of xAxis to change if I addPoint(). I want the axis to remain fixed so that when I add the new point the dimensions of the old chart do not change.